# Finding the value stored in an memory C/C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Lets say i have an function which takes an integer value, Now, in the function i want to know the value which is stored in the memory location pointed by that integer value.

```
void function(int a)
{
  //say, a=10 then I want to know the value stored in memory address 10
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is not a suitable type for passing pointers reliably on any system, without a risk of causing undefined behavior.

Starting with [C99](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) / [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) you can use `uintptr_t` type, which can be converted to and from a pointer:

```
// In C++ include <cstdint>
#include <stdint.h>

void function(uintptr_t a) {
    uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t*)a;
    uint8_t val = *ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++:

```
int function(int a)
{
    return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(a);
}
```

Or in C (also works in C++):

```
int function(int a)
{
    return *(int*)a;
}
```

Of course this will only work if the address actually fit into an `int` in the first place; on 64-bit systems where `int` is 32 bits wide, it doesn't really make sense.  You could use `uintptr_t` as the argument type instead, as that is guaranteed to be wide enough to hold an address (i.e. a pointer).

And I chose to interpret the memory location as an `int`, but you need to use the appropriate return type (e.g. if the address is at the end of a page and you dereference a 4-byte int, your program may crash).